# My code is picking up as if it were all consonant letters

Tags: javascript

My code is picking up as if it were all consonant letters. Please help me.

```js
function contagem() {
   texto = document.getElementById('ftexto').value;
   vogal = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
   consoante = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
   totV = 0;
   totC = 0;

   for (x = 0; x < texto.length; x++) {
      if(x == consoante) {
          totC++;
      } else (x == vogal); {
          totV++;
      }
   }

   alert("Essa palavra possui " + totV + " vogais e " + totC + " consoantes.")
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, your `else` clause is also invalid. Either drop the comparison, or change it to `else if (...)` and do not add a `;` after it

Comment: Would be easier to check against `vogal`, then you wont need the longer `consoante` array.

Comment: @mardubbles If you only check against vogal then your `else` statement would count not only consonants, but spaces, punctuation, and other characters as well. Therefore, if OP wants a count of only vowels & a count of only consonants, then both arrays are necessary.

Comment: Good point @JoshuaCraven

Answer (score 1):

**Using match to count letters**

You could do this in a more simple way using JavaScript [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Example:

```
  let toC = text.match(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/gi) || [];
  let toV = text.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || [];
```

Include the letters you want to count inside the brackets `[]`. The `/gi` instructs match to search the entire text for both lower and upper case letters. And the `|| []` at the end is the default value when no matches are found.

You can then use `toC.length` to get the number of matches and `toC.join()` to get the characters.

**Run the code snippet to understand how it works**

```js
ftexto.addEventListener("input", e => {

  // count vogal and consoate
  let text = ftexto.value;
  let toC = text.match(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/gi) || [];
  let toV = text.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || [];

  message.innerHTML = "Essa palavra possui " + toV.length + " vogais (" + toV.join() + ") e " + toC.length + " consoantes (" + toC.join() + ")";

});
```

```html
<h4>Digite uma palavra:</h4>
<input id="ftexto">
<h4 id="message"></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a character is vowel or consonant you should not use `==`.

It should be checked as the following:

```
if(consoante.includes(texto[x])){
    totC++;
}
else{
    totV++;
}
```

here `x` is the index used to access a particular character from `texto`

Comment: Please update your answer to also clarify that you are using `x` to obtain the actual character via `texto[x]`. In the OP's code, they check against the value of `x`, which will be a number

Answer (score 0):

To begin, you should declare your variables using `const` or `let`.

This also applies to your `for` statement when you declare `x`.

Next, your `if` statement is checking if `x` (which is going to be a number, as you've set in your `for` statement) is equal to `consoante`, which you've declared as an array of strings.

What you're trying to do is check and see if the character in the string `texto` at the index `x` is included in the array `consoante`. We can accomplish that thusly:

`if(consoante.includes(texto[x]))`

Finally, since you are checking another condition with your `else` statement, you need to use `else if`.

The code below works as expected.

```js
function contagem() {
   const texto = document.getElementById('ftexto').value;
   const vogal = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
   const consoante = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
   let totV = 0;
   let totC = 0;
   
   for (let x = 0; x < texto.length; x++) {
   if(consoante.includes(texto[x])){
    totC++;
    } else if (vogal.includes(texto[x])) {
      totV++;
    }
 }

   alert("Essa palavra possui " + totV + " vogais e " + totC + " consoantes.")
}

contagem();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ftexto" value="abcde"></div>
```